# Add value of an edittext to a textview with button click

Tags: android

Im currently working on a small project. Which has a textview, a button and a edittext. The textview is set to 1 and when the button is clicked the textview goes up by 1. I can fill the edittext with any number (including -1 for example). I need to get the value from the edittext and add it to the current value in the textview with the click of the same button. How do i do this? this sounds really easy but i cant seem to find a solution.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int numberText = 1;
    EditText  editTextID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textViewID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        textViewID.setText("1");
    }
    public void changeValue(View view){
        numberText+=1;
        TextView textViewID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        textViewID.setText(numberText+"");

    }
}
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.238" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PlusID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="changeValue"
        android:text="@string/plus"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewID"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewID"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textViewID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PlusID"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/PlusID"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/PlusID" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, you have to bind the editTextID variable with the layout, using the findView method. Then, you can do the same you did with the TextView, but you don't have always to instanciate it, you can create a global variable, as you did with your EdiText, and create the instance at the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get EditText value as follows within changeValue:

```
EditText editTextID = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
try {
    int editValue = Integer.parseInt(editTextID.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // edit text value not a valid integer
}
```

Then it should be simple to add editValue to numberText and display in the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentNum=Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
        int addedNum=Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        currentNum+=addedNum;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(currentNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
public void changeValue(View view) {

    // Retrieve the content from EditText
    editTextID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    String content = editTextID.toString();

    // Then the value of that content
    // Wrap below statement in a try-catch for a NumberFormatException
    int value1 = Integer.parseInt(content);

    // Add it to value from TextView
    TextView textViewID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);

    // Wrap below statement in a try-catch for a NumberFormatException
    int value2 = Integer.parseInt(textViewID.toString());

    // Finally set the correct value
    int value = value1 + value2;
    textViewID.setText(value + "");

}
```

Also, store the references to `TextView` and `EditText` as class fields rather than calling `findViewById()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising the required views first & storing the View instances... It would make your task a lot easier.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView displayValueTextView;
        private EditText valueEditText;
        private Button button;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initViews();
        }

        private void initViews(){
            displayValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_value);
            valueEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }
```

Here's the XML layout so you don't get confused about the Views and their associated Id's;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rl_activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Hello World"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:ems="9"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="@string/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="changeValue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et_input"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_input"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

The onClick attribute of the Button is set to changeValue this is our method that will change the value of our TextView, dependent on what number is on your EditText. This method is shown below:

```
public void changeValue(View view) {
    double numberToAdd;
    double currentValue;

    try {
        numberToAdd = Double.parseDouble(valueEditText.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Edit Text must contain a number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        valueEditText.setText("");
        numberToAdd = 0;
    }
    try {
        currentValue = Double.parseDouble(displayValueTextView.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        currentValue = 0;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current value is not a number. It is now set to 0.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        displayValueTextView.setText("0");
    }

    double finalValue = currentValue + numberToAdd;
    displayValueTextView.setText(finalValue + "");

}
```

The numberToAdd variable is the number we are adding to our current TextView... We must;

1. Extract the value the EditText holds by getting it's text and parsing it as a double (this will allow us to handle decimals numbers in the EditText).
2. We then extract the current value of our TextView (if it is not a number an exception will be thrown and the textview will default to 0).
3. Finally we add the two values and set the TextView as the string representing the added values.